# Changing the positioning of elements using just css

Tags: html, css

I have a webform that has inputs wrapped in divs that look something like this

```
Name
tbFirstName  lblFirstName  tbLastName lblLastName
```

Here is the html markup for it

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <label>Name:</label>
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
<span>
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" />
    <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
</span>
</div>
```

I was wondering on how i could change the output to look like this instead using just css

```
Name
tbFirstName  tbLastName 
lblFirstName lblLastName
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.editor-field span {float: left; margin-right: 10px;} // the margin is optional
.editor-field input {display: block;}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. What exactly does :display: block" do to the input?

Comment: Thanks for the tick... "display: block;" turns the input into a block-level element (adds a natural line-break and a few other things). The input is an inline element by default.

Comment: Thanks tom. If i were to move the position of the label element to be before the input then would i just need to change editor-field input portion to .editor-field span label { display:block;} or is there something else i would need to do?

Comment: @zSysop: yes, that's correct. You'd make that change in the CSS and swap the order of the elements in the HTML, as the answerer below has it. It doesn't really matter whether the "display: block;" is applied to the input or the label... the outcome is the same.

Comment: The answer below is displaying the labels on top of the inputs though. No idea why this is happening. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @zSysop: It's because of the order of the elements in the HTML... if the label is first, it's displayed on top of the input... and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

I moved your labels before the inputs.

```
.editor-field span {float:left;}
.editor-field span label {display:block;}
```

Markup

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <label for="Certnum">Name:</label>
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
<span>
    <label for="Certnum">Last Name</label>
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" />
</span>
<span>
    <label for="Certnum">First Name</label>
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The labels are displaying on top of the input instead of underneath.

Comment: @zSysop - Read my comment above the css, I moved your labels before the inputs, however, you can just as easily keep your markup the same way and style it using css I wrote and it'll work fine.